# SmoothDraw Alternative to Make Videos like Khan Academy

Tags: software-recommendation, drawing

I want to make educational videos like [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/) on my Mac. I am looking for a good app that works just like [SmoothDraw](http://www.smoothdraw.com/product/index.htm) -- which is what Khan Academy uses. I have found apps that let me draw on the screen using a tablet, however I have not found one that lets me scroll the "whiteboard" down in the way SmoothDraw does.

What app would you recommend as the equivalent of SmoothDraw for the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Krita](https://krita.org). It works on Mac, Windows, and Linux. It's designed more for painting, but it should work just fine for this.

I believe it works with tablets, although I'm not 100% sure. It doesn't have an infinite canvas (if you even need that), but you can always start with a canvas bigger than the screen and use it like a whiteboard. Middle-clicking-and-holding will scroll the canvas. (If you don't have a three-button mouse, hold Space and drag. Two-finger scrolling will *not* work.)

Plus, it's free and open source!

---

If you do need an infinite canvas, try [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org). Unlike Krita, it uses vectors, so you can zoom in and out without worrying about quality. I don't think it supports graphics tablets, though.

If you go this route, when you launch Inkscape it will ask you to install X11. Be aware that it won't work quite like other Mac apps—it's running in its own windowing system. One main difference is that Ctrl will work as an alternate Cmd key.

Comment: I couldn't find Krita on the ipad app stores as of Jan 24, 2021

Comment: Oh! Yeah Apple doesn't really allow most open source apps on iOS (they often use the GPL which conflicts with App Store licensing stuff), so Krita won't be there, nor will Inkscape. I was talking about special graphics tablet hardware, Krita runs on the computer and you just _draw_ on the tablet... I think there are a few apps that can make an iPad behave like a graphics tablet though.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft OneNote works well for me as a more complex software. Optimized for touch also for an easy use with a stylus.